# upload new build to same version using fastlane?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane

I have an existing app and want to use `Fastlane`
so after adding some configuration I want to send the new build to testflight,

so I use this lane

```
platform :ios do
   
    private_lane :staging_build do
        increment_build_number(xcodeproj: './ios/myapp.xcodeproj')
        gym(scheme: 'myApp', workspace: './ios/myapp.xcworkspace')
    end

   
    desc 'Build & send to testflight'
    lane :upload_to_testF do
        staging_build
        upload_to_testflight(username: '*****@gmail.com', app_identifier: 'com.comp.myapp')
        commit_version_bump(message: 'bump build')
        push_to_git_remote
    end 

end
```

So after run
`fastlane ios send_to_testF`

> .ipa file generated and build number increment

I got this error after all

```
ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.0.14' is closed for new build submissions"
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0.14] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0.14]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
```

I have this version in the app store

[image: app]

and here's the same in Xcode

[image: xcode]

so why do they ask to increment it!
even I just try and incremented it to 1.0.15 in both code & app store but still got the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple connect wont accept new release with the same version number, but you can let fastlane handle that to ensure you wont miss something. Use something like:

```rb
...
increment_version_number(
  version_number: "1.0.15" # Set a specific version number
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to retrieve the current build for the current version on appStore and auto increment this build number:

```
current_version = get_version_number(
    xcodeproj: xcodeproj,
    target: ENV["TARGET"]
  )
  latest_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
    version: current_version,
    app_identifier: ENV["BUNDLE_ID"]
  )
  build_number = (latest_build_number + 1)
  increment_build_number(
    xcodeproj: xcodeproj,
    build_number: build_number,
  )
```

While `ENV["BUNDLE_ID"]` is the project bundle ID, `xcodeproj` is your xcodeproj name & `ENV["TARGET"]` is the specific target is being used in the current build.